ContentView width not MatchParent in BottomSheetDialog in Android
this is my layout xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="2560px"
        android:layout_height="1080px"
        android:background="#E91E63"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

this is my customize dialog extend BottomSheetDialog

class AppPanel(context: Context) : BottomSheetDialog(context) {

    companion object{
        private const val TAG = "AppPanel"
    }

    init {
        window?.apply {
            setDimAmount(0F)
            setCancelable(true)
            setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog)
    }
}


when I show this appPanel , it's width doesnot match parent.
enter image description here
I also modify dialog's window layoutparams,but not effective.
any one can help me ? thanks very much
content view width should match_parent
